# Android XML attribute style

Tags: android, coding-style

Why is it that some attributes like `android:layout_width` is *put together* with an underscore? While e.g `android:textColor` is instead using camel-casing?

Why not stick entirely with one style (either underscore or camel-casing)?

Comment: Why -1? I think this is a perfectly valid question, to which a precise answer can be given.

Comment: @Malcolm Maybe it's too basic, but this was one of the things I **didn't** even learn in class. Also, thanks for the explanation! (+1)

Comment: Am I the only one who think the reason specified below is not valid?

Comment: I have already said that to me this question seems perfectly fine. Of course, Android developers didn't give the explanation explicitly. But the answer is rather obvious, and I don't see why this question should lead to debates or extended discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are not cases of different style. The second case is a simple attribute which is used by an element. The first one is an attribute which is assigned to an *element*, but is used by a *layout*. This is emphasized by the underscore-separated prefix. If you happen to look at such an attribute as `android:layout_marginTop`, you'll see that these two seemingly separate styles are actually parts of a single idea.

Comment: Yeah, when you see an underscore in these, it's because it's a way of creating a pseudo namespace for that attribute.. like you said layout_ prefixes layout related attributes